# ASP.Net Charts LabelURL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-charts

I've got some graphics working with the MS Asp.Net Chart controls, I noticed the labels have a label URL property, If I put a URL in there then it makes that label a link.

My question is, is it possible to have the label URL be dynamic for each entry in the graph for example I have a graph plotting how many tasks are outstanding for each project. I want the URL to go to the home page for each project.

e.g `Http://www.mywebsite.com/projects.aspx?projectId=*InsertProjectIdHere*`

I'm sure this must be quite a common thing to do so i'm guessing it is possible.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't find satisfaction here, you might try the control's forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MSWinWebChart/threads/

Answer (score 2):

If your x series has the project id in it, you can do

`labelUrl = "Http://www.mywebsite.com/projects.aspx?projectId=#VALX"`

Comment: thanks vitule, ur code realllllllllllllly solved my issue, thanks alotttttttttttt